# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jpype'

Tags: python, jpype

I am using Anaconda Python and used the following to install jpype:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jpype1
```

I have GCC installed:

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:04:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

and I did not get any error during installation.

```
conda install -c conda-forge jpype1 
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

If I run `pip search jpype` I will get the following:

```
jtypes.jpype (0.6.3b3)  - A Python to Java bridge (ctypes/cffi-based JPype).
JPype1-py3 (0.5.5.2)    - Python-Java bridge. Fork of the jPype project by Steve Menard (http://jpype.sourceforge.net/), with the modifications applied by Luis Nell
                          (https://github.com/originell/jpype)
```

but still cannot call the library

```
>>> import jpype
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jpype'
```

Comment: You could install it using `pip` as shown [here](https://pypi.org/project/JPype1/)

Answer (score 6):

It might be because it is installed as a Python 2 package and you're running Python 3 or the opposite.

To specifically install the package for Python 3, try entering this command:

```
pip3 install jpype1
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install jpype1
```

To specifically install the package for Python 2, try entering this command:

```
pip2 install jpype1
```

or

```
python -m pip install jpype1
```

Comment: I get the error using pip3
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Did you install gcc using conda? If that's the case then I think there is a similar issue posted here https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype/issues/182. You can follow the approach in the link by running `conda install gcc` while conda environment was active.

Comment: conda install gcc
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
But still:
pip3 install JPype1
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
By mistake, I had two versions of Anaconda 3.6 and 3.7 which was causing the problem.